# Optimize integer and floating point multiplication

Tags: c++, c, floating-point

I am trying to optimize following operation where I have a large number of unsigned short inputs which needs to be scaled down by a certain factor. Is there a way to optimize it to not use floating point operations

```
unsigned short val = 65523U;
val = val * 0.943;
```

**Note**

I will be running above operation on a DSP where floating point operations are costly

Comment: You could use [fixed-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic). This is commonly used in systems that don't have performant floating-point capabilities.

Comment: Could we use a 32 bit type for `val`?

Comment: Why do you need to optimize it? Have you benchmarked and measured that the multiplication is to slow? To slow for what? How often are you doing this? What is the target platform?

Comment: How much inaccuracy in the result will you tolerate ?

Comment: If memory is not an issue, a look up table might help.  (Pre-calculate all the values and store in an array).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude We will be running this code on a DSP where floating operations are costly. We do this thousands of time per second.

Comment: @Bathsheba Intermediate values can be 32 bit type

Comment: I understand. But that is crucial and very relevant information that should have been part of the question. Next time please include such information in the body of the question.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Accuracy till 4 digits is fine

Comment: Can you not work in `int` throughout (assuming 32 bit `int`). My suspicion is that could be faster anyway,.

Comment: @Bathsheba I am dealing with legacy code, changing this may have some implications. Will try

Comment: If this is for some semi-obscure DSP then you should definitely use the `stdint.h` types. They are kind of mandatory when writing professional embedded systems firmware anyway.

Comment: A subtle difference involves if `0.943` is mean to be 943/1000 or the closest `double` to 0.943 which is likely 0.942999999999999949.....  Is the precise result of concern, (rounding important?) or just something nearby that is fast?  Will this factor change in subsequent code versions?  Is the task with`unsigned short ` or _always_ a 16-bit as in `uint16_t`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mult / divide thing is good. But even better is that you can avoid the divide.

unisgned short has a range 0 ... 65535.

All maths calculations in the CPU are internally handled as 32 bit numbers. But they get cast back to 16 bit after the computation. You want to avoid that if you're multiplying a short by a large number. The output will be a short, causing it to truncate the value. So I put casts in to show what's going on and to make sure there's no extra type casting going on from the compiler.

```
unsigned short val = 65523U;

const unsigned int mult = 65536 * 0.943; // expressed as a fraction of 2^16

unsigned short output = (unsigned short)(((unsigned int)val * mult) >> 16));
```

So this casts the value to 32 bit unsigned int (to guarantee control of the types), multiplies it by up to 2^16 based on the original fraction, then right-shifts it by 16 to put it back in the correct scale.

Comment: While this might indeed save some execution time, it might actually be less accurate, as it will inherit the potential floating point inaccuracy. Your code gave the result 61787 on my computer, whereas the integer division version gives the more accurate 61788. You'd have to invent some trick to correctly round the floating point constant at compile time.

Comment: I've assumed that the float is in fact an arbitrary float in my example, and that as such, expresssing it as x / 65536 will be more accurate - on average - than expressing it as x / 10^n. Obviously if you know for a *fact* that only a floats with a set amount of base-10 accuracy are used then the 943 / 1000 approach will be more accurate, but what about "general case"?

Comment: Well... your version doesn't allow user input at all. `65536 * 0.943` has to be a compile-time constant or this code will be much slower than the original code...

Comment: This is just an example. We have to assume that in the wild it will be used for any possible input. Coding in an entire function with input parameters would only clutter the example.

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way is to just use a 32 bit type that can hold the result:

```
uint16_t val = 65523U;
val = (uint_fast32_t)val * 943 / 1000;
```

Or if you want more type correctness and portability, while at the same time allowing the compiler to use the best possible integer type for the task:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint_fast16_t val = UINT16_C(65523);
val = (uint_fast16_t) ( (uint_fast32_t)val * (uint_fast32_t)943 / (uint_fast32_t)1000 );
```

Comment: It's certainly the way I would do it for a first pass but since it is running on a DSP with slow floating point operations, there is also the possiblity that it has slow division too. Therefore,  nwellnhof's answer might provide a further performance boost.

Answer (score 8):

You can multiply with an integer approximation of 0.943 * 2^16, then divide by 2^16 which your compiler should transform into a right shift. Assuming 16-bit shorts and at least 32-bit ints:

```
val = ((unsigned)val * 61800) / 65536;
```

Depending on your exact requirements, you might get more accurate results by rounding to the nearest integer:

```
val = ((unsigned)val * 61800 + 32768) / 65536;
```

Any other power of two will work. On a 64-bit platform, you could use 2^48 for more precision.

Comment: Since it's being cast back to 16 bits then I think the added precision will all be lost.

Comment: @JasonLang Yes, but using a scale factor of 2^48 allows for a more exact representation of the factor 0.943.

Comment: Only the representation. But that representation is lost, and I'm not sure that the increased resolution will actually translate to a single bit changed in the result

Comment: you see, the output is 0 ... 65535 so multiplying that by 0.943 can at most make a different of 1 out of 65536 in the output representation. The 17th bit which is the highest bit of extra precision of using 48 bits for the representation has a value of 1 part per 131072.

Comment: Please note that this code won't work on 8/16 bit systems. `65523 * 61800 = 48568` and so on. The OP is using some DSP which might very well be 16 bit.

Comment: Perhaps `val = (val * 61800U + 32768) / 65536;`?  or `UL`

Comment: @JasonLang `((unsigned)val * 61800) / 65536;` is certainly different than `((unsigned)val * 61800 + 32768) / 65536;`  Try with `val = 65523`.  Which is closer to `0.943 * 65523`?

Answer (score 1):

you could multiply by `943` then divide by `1000`. You'd save a floating point division (but you'd do a multiplication + an euclidian division).

```
unsigned short val = 65523U;
val = (val*943UL)/1000;
```

I get: `61788`

it works (even on systems where `int` is 16-bit wide) as long as `var*943` is within `unsigned long` capacity (`unsigned long long` could be used to extend the limit even further).

you could multiply by `943` then divide by `1000`. You'd save a floating point division (but you'd do a multiplication + an euclidian division).

```
unsigned short val = 65523U;
val = (val*943UL)/1000;
```

I get: `61788`

it works (even on systems where `int` is 16-bit wide) as long as `var*943` is within `unsigned long` capacity (`unsigned long long` could be used to extend the limit even further).

EDIT: You could even avoid division computing the ratio times a power of 2, I chose 16:

So `.943*(1<<16)` which is `61800.448`

and you could do one multiplication and one shift operation (very fast). It's better to use `unsigned long long` at this point because the intermediate result can get very large:

```
val = (val*61800UL)>>16;
```

to get roughly the same result: `61787`. Use `61801` and you get `61788`

Comment: Beware systems with 16 bit int.

Comment: you're right! edited with `long`. Maybe `unsigned long long` would be overkill?

Comment: I wonder if it's better to use an `int` if you can. I can't see the cast of `val` being cheap.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Is it possible to implement this avoiding division ?

Comment: I don't divide, I'm shifting by 16 steps after having computed the right multiplication value. But someone else answered the same thing in the meanwhile...

Comment: `val = (val*943UL)/1000;` is a bit less cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

With a platform that uses a 32 bit `int` or higher, using

```
int val = 65523U;
val = val * 943 / 1000;
```

would be hard to beat. Convert the truncation to German rounding by altering the coefficients. If your system has a 16 bit `int` then you could use a `long` (note then that the multiplication by 943 and division by 1000 would take place in `long` arithmetic) but the solution would require profiling.

Dividing by `1000` first would cause truncation issues; a larger type is required to accommodate the larger value.

Comment: @nwellnhof: Thank you. (If I had a dollar every time I had done that.) All fixed now. Fancy a job as a code reviewer!?

Comment: You can't use an int to store the result where an int is -32767 to 32768, you are assuming that its a 32bit system ?

Comment: I am indeed assuming that; which I make clear (I think) in my answer. I've added a note on argument promotion for clarity). A platform with a 16 bit `int` would require a separately tailored solution.